# How to Bind Mount using docker-compose.yml for Drupal Image?

Tags: docker, drupal

I am trying to bind mount my Drupal-Image with docker-compose.yml file but it doesn't work exactly how I want it:

```
version: '3.2'

  services:

    drupaldb:
      image: mysql:latest
      ports:
        - 2306:3306
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=drupal
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
      volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: ./mysqldata
          target: /var/lib/mysql
      restart: always

    drupal:
      image: drupal:8-apache
      ports:
        - 8090:80
      depends_on:
        - drupaldb
      volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: ./drupaldata
          target: /var/www/html/sites
      restart: always
```

A file has been created but it is empty! On the Page "Choose Language" I am not able to select German (only English can be chosen). Furthermore other files which are necassary for the installation are missing so that I am not able to install Drupal properly.

I would be very thankful if someone can help me with this or others who have the same issue just like me :)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using [Lando](https://docs.devwithlando.io/tutorials/drupal8.html), it works on top of Docker, you can configure it to suit your needs, it is reasonably well documented.

> Lando is for developers who want to:
>
> 1. Quickly specify and painlessly spin up the services and tools needed
>      to develop their projects.
> 2. Specify these local development
>      dependencies in a per-project, lives-in-git config file called
>      .lando.yml
> 3. Automate complex build steps, testing setups, deployments
>      or other repeated-more-than-once workflows
> 4. **Avoid the built-in-masochism** of directly using docker or docker-compose
>
> It's a **free, open source, cross-platform**, local development environment and
>   DevOps tool built on Docker container technology

- From the Lando website https://docs.devwithlando.io/.

My configuration file is this simple:

```
name: my-drupal-site
recipe: drupal8
config:
  webroot: .
services:
  appserver:
    xdebug: true
```

Also, there are [Docksal](https://docksal.io/) and other [similar projects](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/docker-development-environments).